# org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException : Illegal initial character: 7536

Tags: scala, avro

I have a dataframe with this schema:

```
root
 |-- docid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- doctype: string (nullable = true)
 |-- documentversion: string (nullable = true)
 |-- control_dev_snr: string (nullable = true)
 |-- control_dev_ver: string (nullable = true)
 |-- parser_version: string (nullable = true)
 |-- intervaltype: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 7536: double (nullable = true)
 |-- 7538: double (nullable = true)
```

When i try to write it in "avro" format with this code:

```
newCvmDF.write.mode("overwrite").format("avro").save(s"s3://path/path2/${folderName}")
```

It returns this error:

> ```
> glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(91)): Exception in User Class
> org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal initial character: 7536
>       at org.apache.avro.Schema.validateName(Schema.java:1147)
>       at org.apache.avro.Schema.access$200(Schema.java:81)
>       at org.apache.avro.Schema$Field.<init>(Schema.java:403)
>       at org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$FieldBuilder.completeField(SchemaBuilder.java:2124)
>       at org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$FieldBuilder.completeField(SchemaBuilder.java:2120)
>       at org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$FieldBuilder.access$5200(SchemaBuilder.java:2034)
>       at org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$GenericDefault.noDefault(SchemaBuilder.java:2417)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters$$anonfun$5.apply(SchemaConverters.scala:177)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters$$anonfun$5.apply(SchemaConverters.scala:174)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
>       at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.foreach(StructType.scala:99)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters$.toAvroType(SchemaConverters.scala:174)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat$$anonfun$6.apply(AvroFileFormat.scala:140)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat$$anonfun$6.apply(AvroFileFormat.scala:140)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat.prepareWrite(AvroFileFormat.scala:140)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:103)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
>       at eu.man.datalake.simba.GlueApp$$anonfun$main$1.apply(man-simba-gluejob-rename-column.scala:60)
>       at eu.man.datalake.simba.GlueApp$$anonfun$main$1.apply(man-simba-gluejob-rename-column.scala:46)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
>       at eu.man.datalake.simba.GlueApp$.main(man-simba-gluejob-rename-column.scala:46)
>       at eu.man.datalake.simba.GlueApp.main(man-simba-gluejob-rename-column.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin$class.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:48)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$$anon$1.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:78)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.launch(ProcessLauncher.scala:142)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$.main(ProcessLauncher.scala:30)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.main(ProcessLauncher.scala)
>
> 2022-04-28 12:33:38,740 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(91)): Exception in User Class
> org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal initial character: 7536
>       at org.apache.avro.Schema.validateName(Schema.java:1147)
>       at org.apache.avro.Schema.access$200(Schema.java:81) 
>       at org.apache.avro.Schema$Field.<init>(Schema.java:403) 
>       at org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$FieldBuilder.completeField(SchemaBuilder.java:2124)
>       at org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$FieldBuilder.completeField(SchemaBuilder.java:2120)
>       at org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$FieldBuilder.access$5200(SchemaBuilder.java:2034)
>       at org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder$GenericDefault.noDefault(SchemaBuilder.java:2417)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters$$anonfun$5.apply(SchemaConverters.scala:177)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters$$anonfun$5.apply(SchemaConverters.scala:174)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334) 
>       at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72) 
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.foreach(StructType.scala:99) 
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters$.toAvroType(SchemaConverters.scala:174)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat$$anonfun$6.apply(AvroFileFormat.scala:140)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat$$anonfun$6.apply(AvroFileFormat.scala:140)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121) 
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat.prepareWrite(AvroFileFormat.scala:140)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:103)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
>       at eu.man.datalake.simba.GlueApp$$anonfun$main$1.apply(man-simba-gluejob-rename-column.scala:60)
>       at eu.man.datalake.simba.GlueApp$$anonfun$main$1.apply(man-simba-gluejob-rename-column.scala:46)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392) 
>       at eu.man.datalake.simba.GlueApp$.main(man-simba-gluejob-rename-column.scala:46)
>       at eu.man.datalake.simba.GlueApp.main(man-simba-gluejob-rename-column.scala)
>       at at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
>       at com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin$class.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:48)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$$anon$1.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:78)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.launch(ProcessLauncher.scala:142)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$.main(ProcessLauncher.scala:30)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.main(ProcessLauncher.scala)
> ```

Comment: it is commonly that you can't have filed with name that started with digit. Can you rename column in the dataframe?

Comment: I can not change the name of the column

Comment: Hi did you got your issues resolved with digit field